# Update a toggle value to "true" in Rails & Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, input, toggle

I am creating a Rails app which contains checkboxes that I would like to store the value of in an external Elasticsearch store.

I've written the controller to handle this task. However, I'm at a loss for how to access this within my view

```
def task_complete(task)
    @Toggle = Task.toggle(task)
end
```

I just need to

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick= ???.toggle(task) value=<% task['complete'] %>" />
```

How is this possible?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to send a request to the server with your task id and completed status.

**example**

```
#.erb view
<input class="task" data-id="<%= task.id %>" type="checkbox" value="<%= task.complete %>" />
```

js with jQuery:

```
//for all checkboxes on the page
$(".task:checkbox").on('change', function() { 
  var url = '.../tasks/' + $(this).data('id') + '/toggle';
  $.post(url, { checked: this.checked });
  //callbacks if needed
});
```

routes.rb

```
resources :tasks do
  post 'toggle', on: :member
end
```

rails tasks controller

```
def toggle
  task = Task.find(params[:id])
  #logic with task and params[:checked]
end
```